# Is it possible to tell the difference between an automatic and manual restart in Phusion Passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a process I'd only like to run when I manually reboot my Rails app by touching tmp/restart.txt, not when Passenger restarts itself after an idle period. Is there anything I can check in my Rails code to determine whether a given reboot was one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not answer you want, but I would simply create short script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch tmp/restart.txt
some other things you want to do
```

Then when you restart aplication manualy through this script, you can do after it whatever you want.

Comment: Very true. I was hoping for something I could use from within my Rails app, though.

Comment: In "some other things" you can add a rake task that will add some field in database or in a file. Then your application can read this value - then it knows if it was restarted, and after reading it should remove this value.

Comment: +1 for separating it from the app start up. If these 'other things' aren't necessary to run every time you load your environment, why tie it to that? A rake task you run separately makes more sense than trying to determine what Passenger is doing.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way at the app level to differentiate them. What are you trying to do?